# how to remove the chatzum search engine from my browser

Tags: browser, search-engines, hijack

I'm using Google Chrome on a Windows 7 computer, and I've noticed that when searching for something by just typing in the address bar, it now returns a search results page from something called 'chatzum', where it used to return a google search results page. I've checked my settings, and google is still my default search provider, so why am I getting this chatzum search results page?

I assume it's some kind of virus, but I haven't been able to find anything that will get rid of it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I was given to this problem was to use some free Antivirus software called Avira (www.avira.com) rather than the antivirus I had been paying for (McAfee). Avira did clear this up for me, and it has been much better at detecting new threats and removing them than McAfee ever was. I'd fully recommend it to anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Settings | Extensions" or in the url place "chrome://extensions/"

- Disable or Delete Extension

Go to "Settings" or in the url place "chrome://settings/"

- Check "Open a specific page or set of pages" and see if chatzum is
  there, delete/remove if so
- Check your "Settings Manage Search Engines" ... delete anything that
  says "chatzum"

Other...

- Check your Control Panel in the Add/Remove Programs

Comment: These were the things that I've already tried... the only things in my extensions are 'new tab' and 'web developer'... so unless the 'new tab' is actually this chatzum thing, then it's not there?

I have also already checked my "manage search engines" settings, and deleted all of the additional search engines apart from Google, which was the default.

Any other suggestions? There is nothing called chatzum in add/ remove programs...

Comment: what happens when you go incognito? But did you check in settings "Open a specific page or set of pages" and see if chatzum is there?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the chatzum extension in Chrome:

- In the right-top of the screen, click on the Settings menu
- Select Extensions
- Look for extension Chatzum Toolbar, click on the trash icon to delete it
- Look for extension New Tab , click on the trash icon to delete it

Comment: As mentioned in my comment on the above answer... there is no Chatzum Toolbar being displayed in the extensions section of the settings, and I've deleted all of the search engines that were there apart from google. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience today when I downloaded a program to convert FLAC files. Although I specified a customized install on everything, I still got stuck with some crapware.

Instead of installing this as an extension, it was actually installed as a program. If neither of these suggestions work for you, Go to Start, type `Add or Remove` and select the first result. Remove Chatzum if you see it. If it has an alternative name, you can sort the programs by date and uninstall any programs that you don't remember installing in the past few days since this started.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion. Chatzum does not actually appear at all in the list of programs installed on my computer. Everything I've read points to it being a browser add-on, as opposed to a program in and of itself. Although it is appearing in my version of Google Chrome at the moment, I wonder if the problem originated from IE? Although I haven't used IE for years, so how this would have happened I don't know. Interestingly, when I go into 'manage add-ons' in IE, 'Chatzum search' appears as the only entry in my list of  search providers, but for some reason, I am not able to remove it.

Comment: Any ideas why this is? I've tried everything I can think of, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: It may not be Chatzum per se, it may be another application that Chatzum installed. Have you looked for any other programs installed on the same day?